# blocking code in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an issue in javascript and cannot solve it. My issue is how to block javascript code in a browser. For example:

```
var i = 0;
function process(){
  if (i < 5){
    i++;
    setTimeout(process, 1000);
  }else {
     console.log(i);
  }
}

process();
```

I want the result of this code to print 5 but when it display 1. Thank all i found my solution.

Comment: You cannot "block" execution in JavaScript. Put your `console.log()` call in an `else` block inside `process()`.

Comment: Blocking code in Javascript! Very bad!! Your users will hate you!!!

Comment: thanks #Pointy i am slove it